# React get state from component variable

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to access the state of a react element. As shown in the screen shot below, I want to get the state of the `accountName` component. However, I can only get the pops. I am wondering if it is possible to get it's state?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Include your codebase and explain

Answer (score 0):

why you couldn't just move the state up to the parent component and just pass  it down to child.
this why you will have access to the state